# Получить не уникальные записи

Tags: mysql, sql

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/635024/1):

```
create table records (id int);
insert into records values (1);
insert into records values (1);
insert into records values (2);
insert into records values (3);
insert into records values (3);
insert into records values (3);
insert into records values (4);
insert into records values (5);

create view v_records as
select * from records;

create view v_unique_records as
select * from v_records group by id;

select * // distinct не предлагать - полей для выбора в реальности не одно
from v_records
where id not in (select id from v_unique_records); // ничего не нашло!!!
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? Почему ничего не находит?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `view` с именем `v_unique_records` будет содержать **все значения поля id** из таблицы `records`, так как вы выбираете полный набор значений. Далее, вы выбираете все записи, у которых id не равен полному набору значений(а он всегда равен, потому что принадлежит этому множеству). Соответственно, вы получите пустое множество и ни одна запись не возвращается. 
Чтобы добиться того, чего вы хотите, нужно дополнительно использовать оператор [Having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), в котором можно задать фильтр с помощью агрегатной функции, в нашем случае задаем ограничение на количество записей в одной группе. Нас интересуют только группы, у которых количество записей равно 1.

Тогда ваш view для получения уникальных значений будет следующий:

```
create view v_unique_records as
select * from v_records group by id having count(id) = 1;
```

[Модифицированный ваш пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3e609/1)

Comment: Не понял... Разве group by не возвращает сам по себе только уникальные записи?

Comment: group by группирует записи, на выходе у вас будут группы 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Кажется дошло. Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите кстати, а в этом запросе подзапрос выбирающий идентификаторы будет выполняться один раз или для каждой записи заново?

Comment: Подзапрос будет выполняться один раз.  Попробуйте посмотреть план выполнения запроса, чтобы убедиться в данном вопросе.

Comment: Я смотрел, но не умею их читать. В смысле не понимаю что они значат...